# Subtracting numeric from date in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, numeric, subtraction

When I execute these script, it works in postgresql;

```
select '2021-09-01'::Date - 1

select current_date -1
```

But when I use this type of subtracting in function, postgresql gives me error like this;

Function usage in declare part :

```
v_date date := p_date - p_number;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: date - numeric
```

Comment: What result do you expect if you pass 3.14 as `p_number`?

Comment: The function will not take a decimal number as input, so I don't have any expectations regarding 3.14.  So "v_date date := p_date - p_number::int;" works for me.

Comment: The cleaner solution is then to declare the parameter as `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`v_date date := p_date - p_number::int;`.

Per [Date/Time Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) you can only subtract an integer,  interval or date from a date.

**Note**: the `::int` cast will round the numeric number.

**UPDATE**

Another option is to make `p_number` be an integer from the start, though this depends on whether it is being used for other purposes where it needs to be numeric.

Comment: See UPDATE for an alternative solution.